# Git On Windows Without Cygwin?

Tags: windows, git, version-control, tortoisesvn, cygwin

Are there any native Git implementations for Windows that do not require Cygwin?  I've become a fan of the TortoiseSVN client, and would really like to see a similar Git client for Windows.

**Edit:** I am also considering [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/), but would prefer to check out a few before I make a decision.

Comment: I use [SmartGit](http://www.shareit.com/affiliate.html?affiliateid=200142144&publisherid=200020344&target=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.syntevo.com%2Fsmartgit%2Findex.html) exclusively. It's extremely refined, and does everything I've ever needed. It's also cross-platform (Windows, OS X, and Linux). It uses msysgit, which is in really great shape nowadays (just set autocrlf=false).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I started GitExtensions about a week ago. Allthough version 0.6 is a pretty complete package, I do not consider it release-ready yet. The toolset should be ready for its first stable release in a few days. There are a few things I need to fix before anyone should use it in production. The most important problem now is that the shell extension part is written in c# and therefore can cause problems. I'm rewriting this in c++ at the moment, should just take another few hours. I also want to build in some features that should prevent users from screwing up (like create a stash ontop of another stash and throwing away work or commiting changes when in the middle of a merge). I allready finished allmost all git commands I ever use (push, pull, fetch, stash, branch, commit, merge, format-patch, am, apply, etc), so it should be usable pretty soon. The toolset is written in C# (.Net 3.5 until version 0.6, later versions use .Net 2.0) except the shell extension part. There is also a visual studio plugin, but this is still pretty basic.

I have not tried TortoiseGit yet btw, but I really like TortoiseSVN!

Henk

Answer (score 14):

There is a [TortoiseGit](http://repo.or.cz/w/TortoiseGit.git) -- Window Explore Extenstion to Operate Git.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [MSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). However this is just the command line git compiled with MingW instead of cygwin. This is not a GUI Tool like TortoiseSVN.

There is [GitExtensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) that takes the same path as Tortoise but it does not look ready yet.

Comment: I've installed a standard msysGit distr. There is a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried looking at the [TortoiseGit page on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)? I believe it's the same project as the other link posted, but it's a bit friendlier. You can download the latest version as an installer from there.